# android/java getIdentifier with

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble getting `getIdentifier` to work with a class variable. It's strange, because this works:

```
public Drawable getStationIcon(Context context) {
    int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("m1m2_16", "drawable", "com.mypackage.namehere");
    Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(resId);
    return drawable;
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
public Drawable getStationIcon(Context context) {
    int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(this.stationIcon, "drawable", "com.mypackage.namehere");
    Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(resId);
    return drawable;
}
```

And nor does this:

```
public Drawable getStationIcon(Context context) {
    String stationI = this.stationIcon;
    int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(stationI, "drawable", "com.mypackage.namehere");
    Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(resId);
    return drawable;
}
```

And `this.stationIcon` definitely equals `m1m2_16`. I've tried other alternatives, ie using `""+this.stationIcon`, but nothing works when the first parameter is a variable. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I would suggest to log `Log.d(TAG, "stationIcon = " + this.stationIcon)` the `this.stationIcon` right before its usage to make sure it is really "m1m2_16".

Comment: I have done so, and it's definitely m1m2_16

Answer (score 2):

Strangely it will probably work:

```
getIdentifier("com.mypackage.namehere:drawable/" + this.stationIcon, null, null);
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/users/790997/idroid

[Resources.getIdentifier() has unexpected behavior when name is numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387387/resources-getidentifier-has-unexpected-behavior-when-name-is-numeric)