# Resources.getIdentifier() has unexpected behavior when name is numeric

Tags: android, string, parsing, resources, localization

I use Resources.getIdentifier to load up string resources dynamically; because I am dynamically passed a string that needs to be translated from my resources files. It returns 0 when the resource doesn't exist; so I handle that. However, when I pass in a string that is a numeric; even though I don't have that defined in my resources, it returns the number I passed in instead of 0. This causes a crash when I try to get that resource.

```
int identifier = context.getResources().getIdentifier(myText, "string", "com.farragut.android.emsspeak");
if (identifier > 0) {
    text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    text2.setText(context.getResources().getString(identifier));
} else {
    text2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Is this defined behavior?? I can't imagine why it works fine when myText is "BLAH" but then when myText is "12" it is different. The only thing I can think of is to test if myText is numeric first; though the only way I can find to do that is to try to parse it as an integer and catch a numberFormatException. Is that the best solution?

Comment: Looks like bug in `getIdentifier` method. You need to post bugreport. Instructions [here](http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well this is kinda weird but if I specify the fully qualified name like it's mentioned in the getIdentifier() documentation it works properly otherwise i got the same result like you.

Try it with `getIdentifier("com.farragut.android.emsspeak:string/"+myText, null, null);`

Comment: Well that's really strange... works like you say, but based on the documentation it sounds like those 2 lines of code should be identical... whether you qualify your name, or pass in the type and package as separate parameters. Oh well... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

String resource can contain only strings no special characters no alphabets as tag name.

**example**

`<string name="mydata">Suuuuu</string>` is valid

`<string name="45645">Suuuuu</string>`  is invalid

**so first check whether your text is valid or not**

Use the following code to get it work for you

**Code**

```
boolean isValid = (Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", myText))

if(isValid){
int identifier = context.getResources().getIdentifier(myText, "string", "com.farragut.android.emsspeak");
if (identifier > 0) {
    text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    text2.setText(context.getResources().getString(identifier));
} else {
    text2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

}
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

I was banging my head to make this work:

```
int imgId = getResources().getIdentifier("moviedetails" + movieId , "drawable", getPackageName());
imageview.setImageResource(imgId);
```

works perfectly fine for me.  just needed : **"Project --> Clean"**